# Error for column count mismatch for JSON, AVRO, ORC and PARQUET file formats

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, avro, parquet, orc

We are using a copy command for loading data into Snowflake. With CSV file format, there is a parameter 'ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH' to get the error if columns present in input CSV file do not match with Snowflake's target database table. Is there any similar parameter for JSON, AVRO, ORC and PARQUET file formats to get the error if there is a column count mismatch?

Comment: Hi - have you tried looking at the Snowflake documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The same parameter is used for other file-formats as well (i.e. JSON, Parquet etc.)

See here -
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#syntax

Comment: If we use 'ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH' parameter for JSON and other file formats, Snowflake throws error saying that this parameter is not supported for JSON file format.